# Binding to a different context depending on Injection targets type

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

I want to be able to use ninject to inject a different type of DBContext into different areas of my application. Does anyone know if you can do this with a ninject When clause?

Something along the lines of:

```
        Bind<DbContext>().To<ServiceContext1>().When(t=>t.Target.Type.Assembly.FullName.StartsWith("Namespace.Context1."));
        Bind<DbContext>().To<ServiceContext2>().When(t => t.Target.Type.Assembly.FullName.StartsWith("Namespace.Context2."));
        Bind(typeof(IRepositoryDataSource<>)).To(typeof(DbContextRepositoryDataSource<>));
        Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(SimpleRepository<>));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.Target.Type` returns the parameter type. You are looking for`request.Target.Member.ReflectedType`. Since you inject the context into the identical repository you probably have to check on the parent request using `request.ParentRequest` or even the grand parent rather than on the request because there you will get always the repository type.